# LightGBM ignore warning about "boost_from_average"

Tags: python, warnings, data-science, lightgbm, boosting

I use LightGBM model (version 2.2.1). It shows next warning on train:

> [LightGBM] [Warning] Starting from the 2.1.2 version, default value
>   for the "boost_from_average" parameter in "binary" objective is true.
>   This may cause significantly different results comparing to the
>   previous versions of LightGBM. Try to set boost_from_average=false, if
>   your old models produce bad results

I found what it is about:[github link](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1514).

But I don't use any old models or legacy code (it's new project created on 2.2.1 version of LightGBM), so I don't need to see this warning every time.

Also I know I can change `verbose` and turn off all warnings. But it's not really good - some another can be useful!

So my question is: **Is it possible to turn off (hide) just this Warning?**

Answer (score -1):

Mikhail

Try to set the parameter boost_from_average when you create the model. Either True or False.

Best Regards,